# How to use focusArea in TYPO3 in the Frontend

Tags: typo3, responsive-images

Like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44562142) you can use a FocusArea in the Backend.

The result in the Frontend looks like this.

```
<img src="..." data-focus-area="{"x":4994,"y":2809,"width":4994,"height":2809}" />
```

What is needed in Frontend so that this focus-area is always visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are jQuery libraries for it.
I doesn't used this feature for now, but a quick look on this seems promising:
[jQuery Focuspoint](https://github.com/jonom/jquery-focuspoint)

Please note that this feature is only relevant if your space for the image is smaller than the image you want to show.

Comment: hi Kevin, thanks for your answer.
I assumed that it was working with core functionality alone.
So if i have to use a ThirdParty Framework, maybe it's easier to use the Extension [FocusPoint](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/focuspoint)

Comment: This extension is using exactly the same jQuery plugin. So why install an extension (that have to be maintained) instead of just include the jQuery plugin?

Comment: hi Kevin, yes that's right i can build and test it on my own or i use an complete extension.

Comment: seems there is no TYPO3 builit in possibility to use this feature in Frontend.
Therefore it is necessary to include a third party Script like Focuspoint

Comment: Can jQuery Focuspoint handle data-focus-area or do we have wirte a new viewhelper for spliting the data-focus-area to 
data-focus-x, data-focus-y, data-image-w and data-image-h?